# How to do asynchronous programming with only global variables?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

If a programming language only supports global variables, is it still possible to use asynchronicity, like callbacks, event-driven programming, other kinds of parallelisation?

How can it be done?

Comment: It could be done with patterns and strong discipline.

Comment: Assembly language only has global variables (registers).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so imagine you restricted yourself in JS to not allow non-global scope variables. The only way to do complex tasks is to simulate memory (using a huge array in a global variable ig) and write JS as if it were assembly?

Comment: There's usually more than one way to accomplish a programming task.

Answer (score 2):

Every program that uses local variables can be converted to one that uses only global variables.  So, the answer is trivially yes.  However, it might not be pleasant for the software developer.

Comment: There's trickery if we also allow recursive calls, but the trickery is doable so long as the global variables can hold complex data (lists, for example).

Comment: "can be converted to one that uses only global variables" is this only true if the language supports arrays or similar?

Comment: @theonlygusti, the language has to be Turing-complete.  So, arrays, yes, or something similar.  Recursive calls have to be translated appropriately (as Andrej Bauer indicates): a natural way is to emulate the call stack by a data structure (a list or stack).